# How to remove outlines surrounding the images when viewing files as thumbnails in the Blender file browser?

Tags: interface, image, customization, file-browser

There are outlines surrounding the images when viewing files as thumbnail in the Blender Browser, how do I remove them?

[image: Figure1]

And if possible, is there a way to remove the logo that shows the file type?

I want the appearance of each element (especially the images) to be the same as that in Figure 2:

[image: Figure2]

Is there any solution to that, even if the solution requires Python programming?

Comment: Nobody answered yet?

Comment: A whole month and no one has answered, why?